# Insertar registro solo si es un dato en especifico MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Tengo esta consulta en MYSQL

```
INSERT INTO psb_smt.psb_info (linea, DateTime, EndDate)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$linea."', '".$StarDate." ".$TimeNow."', '".$EndDate." 06:39:00') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DateTime, EndDate, linea FROM psb_smt.psb_info WHERE linea = '".$linea."' AND 
    DateTime >= '".$StarDate." 06:40:00' AND EndDate<='".$EndDate." 06:39:00'
) LIMIT 1
```

Son datos que envio por **$_POST** y otras **variables** que me definen la fecha y hora.

La consulta funciona perfectamente, el dilema esta en que yo quiero que especificamente solo me deje insertar registros con el dato *"Linea 01"*, *"Linea 02"* etc.. hasta *"Linea 06"* por que cualquier dato ingresado en linea es aceptado y no es el punto... me gustaria lograr que solo inserte si el dato linea son los mencionados anteriormente, espero haber explicado bien el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen anterior es de mi tabla de **psb_info**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías tener un array con los valores válidos y verificar si `$linea` existe en ese array:

Algo así:

```
$validLines=array("Linea 01","Linea 02","Linea 03","Linea 04","Linea 05","Linea 06");
if ( in_array($linea,$validLines) ){
   //Aquí lanzar el INSERT
} else {
   //No se lanzará el INSERT, mostrar un mensaje o lo que quieras
}
```

La ventaja de hacerlo así es que no tendrás que echar mano de la base de datos en los casos en que no sea necesario insertar, ahorrando recursos.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio no lo habia pensado de esa manera :)

Comment: @EduardoMX me alegro de que haya servido. Saludos.